# SSL Handshake Error With Docker and Selenium trying to access website

Tags: python, docker, selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script which is running Chrome with chromedriver and selenium.
When I run the script without Docker it works normally and I access the website, if in Docker the Exception gets shown in the Browser with a 502 Gateway Error.
My theory is that I need to configure the SSl Settings in the Docker Container, but I dont know exactly how
Error shown in Chrome in Docker(Selenium):

````
TlsProtocolException('Cannot establish TLS with accounts.ea.com:443 (sni: accounts.ea.com): 
TlsException("SSL handshake error: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'\', \'unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled\')])")')```
````

Comment: same issue.. did you find a solution?

Comment: @Manspof yes you need to downgrade some packages. In my case it was the package cryptography. Are you still interested? I would provide more details if yes